# How to Compile Flash .fla into .swf via command line?

Tags: windows, flash, compiler-construction

How to compile Flash .fla files into .swf via command line on a Windows based operating system.  Command line tools that need to be installed are ok.
Can anyone suggest me what to do? (in a straight forward way).  :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `JSFL` to script the Flash IDE and tell it to compile an FLA to a SWF.  Here are a few examples.

http://labs.flexperiments.nl/compiling-flash-files-from-flex/

http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2004/08/jsfl_fla_batch.html

And here's a utility app to simplify:

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2003/11/01/flashcommand-flash-2004-command-line-compiler/

Comment: Has anyone found a way not using JSFL/loading the IDE? It is ludicrous to load an IDE on a headless build machine.

Comment: The first url is broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to compile FLA file into SWF up to Flash CS4 (that may be flash10 I guess) this may come useful;
[fla2swf](http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/08/02/Automate-FLA-Publishing-with-FLA2SWF)

Answer (score -6):

There is no way to compile FLA files to SWF files via the command line.

Comment: I don't think this is entirely true, since FlashDevelop manages to send a compile instruction to the Flash IDE, you need to have the File open in the Flash IDE, and it might be a little more complex than 'compile *file*' but, it can certainly be done.

Comment: That is probably not an optimal solution.

Comment: what UberNeet was basically saying is that FlashDevelop can tell Flash IDE to compile, so it's presumptuous of you to say compiling from the command line is not possible (especially since it is possible via jsfl).

Comment: And yet, there is still no way to actually compile via only the command line, to this day. JSFL is not sufficient.