# Build MediaElement flash component in Ubuntu

Tags: flash, apache-flex, ubuntu, compilation, mediaelement.js

I am new to flash, this is the first time i put my hands on into this. And am really struck compiling [MediaElement](https://github.com/realgravity/mediaelement) in Ubuntu. As per the instruction in the [`build.sh`](https://github.com/realgravity/mediaelement/blob/bae1f39fb38d7f085b75e1c31b6cb8181507d11a/src/flash/build.sh) (From realgravity forked branch) file

- I have downloaded and installed Flex SDK for linux
- symlinked it to my flash src directory
- And used `compc` to create the `swc` file from `fla`. This is the command

  ```
   ./flex_sdk_4.6/bin/compc -source-path . -output flashmediaelement.swc
  ```

  But i am getting the execption `Error: nothing was specified to be included in the library`
- SO i copied the [`flashmediaelement.swc`](https://github.com/realgravity/mediaelement/blob/bae1f39fb38d7f085b75e1c31b6cb8181507d11a/src/flash/flashmediaelement.swc) (5 months old)
- Now i build the 'swf' using the `mxmlc`

  ```
  mxmlc -strict=false -warnings=true ./FlashMediaElement.as -o ../../build/flashmediaelement-debug.swf -library-path+="$FLEXPATH/lib" -include-libraries+=./flashmediaelement.swc -use-network=true -headless-server -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries
  ```

  Build was successful and got the swf. But it was not working properly because i used the 5 months old `flashmediaelement.swc` .

Now i need your help to compile `FlashMediaElement.fla` to create `flashmediaelement.swc` using the `compc`. I would really appreciate any help or hint resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> used compc to create the swc file from fla

An .fla file is not source code.  It is like a project file for Flash Professional.  You won't be able to do anything with an .fla using Flex tools, such as the command line compiler.

I do not believe Flash Professional supports Linux in any way.  A bit more info on that [can be found in this question about compiling a .fla from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068669/how-do-i-compile-flash-flas-using-command-line).

To create a SWC from an .fla you'll have to open the fla in Flash Professional and [export the contents as a SWC](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001912.html).  There also usd to be a Flash Pro plugin which would allow you export individual library elements as SWCs for use with Flash Pro.  More info on that [process and workflow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSFD77A256-0DE1-46c7-86FB-CC4A8AE2EAA6.html#WS5F9A13A1-03CB-4a01-B467-0272D23A12D0).